# Can't run kibana in cloud run

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, kibana, google-cloud-run

I have been trying to run kibana (from elasticsearch) in Google Cloud Run without success.

The container runs perfectly in my local computer, but it fails in Cloud Run.
I have tried a lot and I am wondering if there is a Cloud Run limitation for running this service with Cloud Run.

This is my `Dockerfile` configuration:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.7.0

ENV ELASTICSEARCH_URL http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200 # this is a public IP
ENV ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200
ENV XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED "true"
ENV ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME kibana
ENV ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD ****

EXPOSE 5601
```

This is my gcloud deploy command:

```sh
gcloud run deploy kibana --image gcr.io/<myprojectid>/kibana \
                        --platform managed --port=5601 \
                        --region=us-central1 --allow-unauthenticated --memory=2Gi
```

and i get

```
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [kibana] in project [rich-meridian-274818] region [us-central1]
✓ Deploying... Done.
  ✓ Creating Revision...
  ✓ Routing traffic...
  ✓ Setting IAM Policy...
```

Then requesting `https://kibana-lfv63mupmq-uc.a.run.app/`  i get `Kibana server is not ready yet`.
And this is in the error log: `Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes.`

What am I missing?

Comment: Kibana is NOT going to run in Cloud Run. The wrong type of service. Cloud Run does not store data, offers one HTTP port, is an HTTP Request/Response system, etc. Use Compute Engine or Kubernetes.

Comment: ok. so kibana have to store data outside of elasticsearch? Is kibana comunicating with elasticsearch with a method different than HTTP requests/responses? I'm trying to understand the whys more than to find an alternative solution.

Comment: I recommend reading https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq#which-applications-are-suitable-for-cloud-run